# MEF composition issue

Tags: c#, mef, composition

I can't solve what seems to be a basic MEF problem:
I have 2 "plugins" project (which we'll call P1 and P2), and a third project that is common to both plugins (which we'll call C). P1 and P2 both reference C.

When trying to import a component that lives in P1, it fails because this component has dependencies on components that live in C.

Here is the trace:

> System.ComponentModel.Composition Warning: 1 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'MyCompany.Client.Pms.Plugin.InclusionList.ViewModel.InclusionListViewModel' has been rejected. The composition remains unchanged. The changes were rejected because of the following error(s): The composition produced multiple composition errors, with 4 root causes. The root causes are provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.
>
> 1) **No exports were found that match the constraint** '((exportDefinition.ContractName = "MyCompany.Client.Plugins.Common.Controls.Selectors.PortfolioSelectors.ViewModel.ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel") && (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentity") && "MyCompany.Client.Plugins.Common.Controls.Selectors.PortfolioSelectors.ViewModel.ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel".Equals(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))'.
>
> Resulting in: Cannot set import 'MyCompany.Client.Pms.Plugin.InclusionList.ViewModel.InclusionListViewModel.CalypsoBookSelectorViewModel (ContractName="MyCompany.Client.Plugins.Common.Controls.Selectors.PortfolioSelectors.ViewModel.ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel")' on part 'MyCompany.Client.Pms.Plugin.InclusionList.ViewModel.InclusionListViewModel'.
>   Element: MyCompany.Client.Pms.Plugin.InclusionList.ViewModel.InclusionListViewModel.CalypsoBookSelectorViewModel (ContractName="MyCompany.Client.Plugins.Common.Controls.Selectors.PortfolioSelectors.ViewModel.ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel") -->  MyCompany.Client.Pms.Plugin.InclusionList.ViewModel.InclusionListViewModel -->  DirectoryCatalog (Path="C:\Work\mmtrader\dashboard\Code\Src\Dashboard\MM\Trader\bin\Debug\Plugins\Positions")

[...] (The 3 other problems are exactly the same, on different view models)

I have looked at the MEF catalog, and it turns out that MEF knows about those view models, so I don't know what's missing.

As requested by Dennis below, here are my import/export:

Export:

```
Export(typeof(ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel))]
public class CalypsoBookSelectorViewModel : ScreenWithCleanupLifecycle, ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel
{...}
```

Import:

```
[Import(typeof(ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel))]
public ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel CalypsoBookSelectorViewModel { get; set; }
```

And the catalog:

[image: Catalog]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found the problem, and it had nothing to do with the CalypsoBookSelectorViewModel that MEF was pointing the finger on.

Indeed, the ViewModel has dependencies on another component (a CalypsoBookSelectorModel), which in turn has a dependency on a IDispatcher component.

The problem was that this IDispatcher component, which was specified with a contract name (see below), was exported **TWICE** (once in each plugin), so MEF couldn't tell which one to use.
The real problem of course is that **MEF should have told me that**, instead of pointing the finger to a class two levels up the chain.

Thanks Dennis for looking at the problem, and I hope this will help other people who'll get the same problem.

The Dispatcher import:

```
[Import(DispatcherNames.BackgroundDispatcherName, typeof(IDispatcher))]
public IDispatcher Dispatcher { get; set; }
```

Comment: Would you mark this as the correct answer? I started looking at MEF recently, and this is useful information!

Comment: I would, but I can't before two days apparently. I'll do that in 48 hours unless someone can do it for me before then!

Comment: @AntoineJaussoin: but MEF tells you about that! :) Look carefully into your output window, and you'll see something like 'More than one export was found that matches the constraint' when constructing that part (depending on `IDispatcher`). Of course, if that part isn't composed, depending parts will not be constructed too. Unfortunately, I don't know how to post code sample here to reproduce this message.

Comment: @Dennis: I looked again on the log, and the only thing I could find was System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'MyCompany.Dashboard.Client.Plugins.Common.Framework.IDispatcher' was ignored because it contains no exports.  The problem is it was in the middle of a lot of other stuff, and unless I knew in the first place that the IDispatcher was the problem, I couldn't have found it!

Comment: It may be that we are using an old version of MEF though, I'm going to take a look at updating it. Maybe a newer version would give more debug info.

Comment: @AntoineJaussoin: I'm using MEF from .NET 4. It is interesting to look at full MEF trace (how to enable it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2010/07/13/how-to-debug-and-diagnose-mef-failures.aspx).

Comment: So how do you avoid this issue in the long term?

Comment: I also have same problem but could not find DispatcherNames.BackgroundDispatcherName. What is this ?

Comment: The error ocurr because he using [Import], for import more than one you should be use [ImportMany]

Answer (score 6):

Your `P1` imports something from `C` (more exactly, `ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel`).

When MEF container tries to create `P1`, it also tries to resolve all imports, which `P1` depends from. Hence, it performs search for export of `ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel` type (indeed, contract name, but it doesn't matter in this case) in its own catalog and parent export providers.

If such export is not found (this is your case), MEF container remains composition unchanged.
To fix this, you should add `[Export(typeof(ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel))]` to the corresponding type definition.

Of course, all this implies, that your catalog and export providers (if there are any) are initialized properly.

Note, that this export definitions are **not** equal:

```
public interface IA {}

[Export(typeof(IA))] // contract name is "IA"
public class A : IA {}

[Export] // contract name is "A"
public class A : IA {}

[Export]
public class Composed
{
    [Import] // MEF will search for exports like [Export(typeof(IA))]
    private IA field1;

    [Import] // MEF will search for exports like [Export]
    private A field1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, many thanks for your reply! Problem is, the Export is properly set on the implementation class: [Export(typeof(ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel))]
    public class CalypsoBookSelectorViewModel : ScreenWithCleanupLifecycle, ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel

Comment: Hi again, I looked at your edited answer, and I do understand all this: I believe my import/export attributes are correct, they properly define the interface etc. On the other hand, it seems that MEF is a bit lying to me as I'm starting to think that the problem is not directly with my ICalypsoBookSelectorViewModel but with another import much down the line (which MEF doesn't tell me about). I'll come back to you if this lead leads somewhere

Comment: I've just added the import/export to the original question

Comment: @AntoineJaussoin: your import/export definitions looks OK; could you post parts from catalog, used in MEF container (e.g., screenshot from debugger)? I don't believe in miracles...

Comment: I posted the screenshot on the original question. I don't believe in miracles either but it could be my lucky day ;)

Comment: I found the problem, it of course had nothing to do with the view model components... MEF is not very helpful for debugging. I'll post my finding in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error ocurr because he using `[Import]`, for import more than one you should be use `[ImportMany]`

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for the solution to this problem after i got into it. I realized that i was using **System.Composition** instead of using **System.ComponentModel.Composition** on the exporting class.